# Problem with Ruby recursive lambda call

Tags: ruby, recursion, lambda

I have the following code that correctly traverses all the nodes in a graph like so:

```
seen = {}
dfs = lambda do |node|
  return if seen[node]
  seen[node] = true
  $edges[node].each {|n| dfs.call n}
end
dfs.call 0
```

However, I would like to write it this way, which I understand is correct:

```
  $edges[node].each &dfs
```

However, when I do this it appears that `dfs` is only being called on the first element of the list of nodes in `$edge[node]`. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/RwUed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, your problem is *not* in the recursion! It actually is because of the shared `seen` collection among all calls in `$nodes[node].each &dfs`.

Let's go through the operation: the call to `$nodes[node].first` should not have any problems, because we know the snippet works for any one node. There is a problem however: `seen` is not reset, and you are already going to the next node! You already saw all the nodes, so when you try even one on the next cycle, it will immediately return out of the proc because of the condition. The same will happen for every other call as you loop through `$nodes`. It only seems that the calls to the rest of the nodes never happened!

To solve your problem, isolate `seen` to the scope of each call of `dfs`, which we can still do in functional programming:

```
dfs = lambda do |node|
  seen = []
  sub_dfs = lambda do |sub_node|
    return if seen.include? sub_node
    seen << sub_node
    $edges[sub_node].each &sub_dfs
  end
  sub_dfs.call node
end

$edges[some_node].each &dfs
```

Now `seen` is safely isolated in each call to `dfs`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make recursive lambdas:

```
fac = lambda{|n, &context| n.zero? ? 1 : n * eval("fac.call(#{n-1}) {}",context.binding)}
```

But have to be called with empty block though

```
fac.call(2){} = 2
fac.call(3){} = 6
fac.call(4){} = 24
```

[binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Proc.html#M000466) is used to evaluate the code outside of lambda scope